# rewrite or internal redirection cycle with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have a PHP API which lives off the URL path `/api` and on OSX the following configuration works fine:

```
location /api {
    try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_pass    PHP:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

This same location block on Ubuntu, however, seems to result in:

> [error] 9#0: *3 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/api/index.php"

This is regardless if I explicitly call `http://localhost/api/index.php`, use a directory reference `http://localhost/api` or if I pass some params to the index.php script with a call like: `http://localhost/api/actions/recent`.

Can anyone help me understand why Ubuntu and OSX might be different? What about getting around this rewrite error?

---

Full details for OSX and Ubuntu can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/80ac9a64a6cb03927838

Comment: added full config. OSX is single file, Ubuntu uses include to arrive at similar results.

Comment: Shot in the dark, cause I see no real issues - you have no error pages defined and the socket path points to a location I don't expect on ubuntu.

Comment: My impression was that the error path, if left undefined, would simply be reported to the access log. Is that not the case?

Comment: WRT to the socket being in an unusual location ... oops that was a cut and paste error. I have corrected as the Ubuntu connection is using TCP sockets not Unix sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my initial supposition that OSX and Ubuntu were behaving differently did not prove to the case.

The turning point for me was understanding a bit more about the genesis of this error. While the text of the error doesn't exactly give it away it basically was indicating that it had tried all variations in the patterns listed on the **try_files** line. In fact many people add a **=404** to the of such a line to resolve to a more meaningful error if no matches are found.

Once I realised what the error was actually saying it led me to the realisation that there was a mismatch in the path being passed to FPM and the directory structure that FPM was expecting. Stupid ... But then all hard errors typically have an element of stupidity. :)